# setImmediate() documentation issue (hopefully)

Tags: node.js, setimmediate

[image]

found this while going thru the documentation

nodejs.org - guide url (left side)

nodejs.dev - url from the guides section (Introduction to Node.js) (right side)

red marked line (left side) - green marked line (right side) are contradicting in their meaning

I feel the green underlined one is correct - please correct my understanding.

Thanks

Comment: Always ask the people who are _most_ suited to answer your question first. Yes, you can ask here, but the only people who can _authoritatively answer this_ is the Nodejs writing team, and they have a public issue tracker, so you _really_ need to ask for docs clarification there, first. And if you haven't yet, even if you posted here, you should _still_ ask over on their docs repo.

Comment: The doc on the right supplies very few specifics, only a generic "next iteration of the event loop".  The doc on the left attempts to supply a lot more detail about when exactly it would run in that next iteration of the event loop.  I don't personally see them as conflicting - one description just offers a lot more detail.